# A-Z filter menu - limiting output to one when there are multiples

Tags: entries, filter

I have a A-Z menu to filter entries by their first letter.

```
   <ul class="directory-letters">
    <li class="all current" data-filter="all">ALL</li>
    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('membershipDirectory').order('title asc') %}
      <li data-filter="letter-{{ entry.companyName|slice(0, 1)|lower|replace("/[^a-z]/", "0-9") }}">{{ entry.companyName|slice(0, 1) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

Issue I have is if there are 4 entries beginning with 'C' the output will be:

A B C C C C D E F...

Can I limit each letter once so I'll get 1 'C' is there are 1+ entries starting with 'C'?

---

UPDATE:

I'm now getting the right number of instances created but no text inside my

. Likely a rookie error somewhere:

```
{% set allEntries = 
craft.entries.section('membershipDirectory').order('title asc') %}
{% set allEntriesByFirstCharacter = 
 allEntries|group('companyName|slice(0, 1)|lower|replace("/[^a-z]/", 
 "0-9")' ) %}

 <ul class="directory-letters">
    <li class="all current" data-filter="all">ALL</li>
    {% for allEntries in allEntriesByFirstCharacter %}
       <li data-filter="letter-{{ entry.companyName|slice(0, 1)|lower|replace("/[^a-z]/", "0-9") }}">{{ entry.companyName|slice(0, 1)|lower|replace("/[^a-z]/", "0-9") }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [group](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/filters.html#filter) filter and create a 2d array with the letter as the first index and the entries as second index.

```twig
{% set allEntriesByFirstCharacter = allEntries|group('companyName|slice(0, 1)|lower|replace("/[^a-z]/", "0-9")' ) %}
```

The string passed in the filter will get rendered as an object template an equal results will be grouped by the same key.

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting empty outputs, but the right number of instances now. Post updated.

Comment: Where do you assign the `entry` variable? You use it but I'm not sure what it should be. Please take a look at the link